# Awesome WM - Application's fullscreen mode without taking whole screen

Tags: awesome-wm

i'm looking for a way to let applications using their own fullscreen mode but without resizing their own windows.

For example, i want to watch a video on a web browser in fullscreen mode to hide all other bars/content of the browser/website except the video but i want to keep my display layout to see other apps at the same time.

Any ideas?
Thanks !

Comment: How can you have a fullscreen app but still see other apps at the same time?

Comment: It's not real fullscreen, I'm looking for a way to hide the interface, for example when you use the fullscreen button on a youtube video it hides everything of the firefox windows except the video and set the windows in fullscreen. I aim to ignore second part.

Answer (score 4):

I did not test the following, but it might work. The idea of the rule is that it is used to detect which windows should not be fullscreend. It is a normal `awful.rules`-rule. All clients which do not match the rule are handled normally by `awful.ewmh.geometry`.

```
local rule = { class = "Firefox" }
client.disconnect_signal("request::geometry", awful.ewmh.geometry)
client.connect_signal("request::geometry", function(c, context, ...)
    if context ~= "fullscreen" or not awful.rules.match(c, rule) then
        awful.ewmh.geometry(c, context, ...)
    end
end)
```

Edit: To toggle this behaviour I suggest the following:

```
local no_fullscreen = true
local rule = { class = "Firefox" }
client.disconnect_signal("request::geometry", awful.ewmh.geometry)
client.connect_signal("request::geometry", function(c, context, ...)
    if not no_fullscreen or context ~= "fullscreen" or not awful.rules.match(c, rule) then
        awful.ewmh.geometry(c, context, ...)
    end
end)
```

Then add a key binding with callback function `function() no_fullscreen = not no_fullscreen end`.

Comment: It works fine but i can't resize/move the  "fullscreen client" anymore. Any thoughts?

Comment: You mean "also cannot resize the fullscreen client when it is not fullscreen", right? See my edit, the code should now only ignore requests when the "context" is "fullscreen". If you mean "cannot resize while fullscreen", then that assumption is buried so deep in the code that it cannot easily be disabled.

Comment: Cool!  I really like this.  Follow-up question:  How can I toggle that behaviour?  Sometimes I'd still like Firefox to go really full screen.

Comment: Sure, just add another condition to the `if`. See my edit.

Comment: I see, thanks. My question would be needless, if Firefox respected the max.fullscreen layout.  Hence my (off-topic) next question: How can I make Firefox respect the max.fullscreen layout or is that just me?

Comment: Uhm... Run `xprop _NET_WM_STATE` in a terminal and click on Firefox. Does it say anything helpful? Is Firefox perhaps made Floating? Dunno.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for but the window is not tiled anymore, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a bug to your benefit: Chrome doesn't notice the WM un-full-screening and stays in full screen mode. So if you only want this for watching a video in a browser using Chrome will work.

I use this with Teams all the time: F11 to enter full screen then my hotkey of mod+F to exit full screen leaves me with no chrome UI but Teams in a window that tiles etc.